# how to convert tuple into dictionary in python

Tags: python-3.x, api, networking

I am connecting to mikrotik via API service and it goes well but the response is a tuple format and when i try to convert it to dict an error raise as shown below.

I tried to write `print(dict(data))`. But it throws out an error 
`ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 24; 2 is required`

```py
from librouteros import connect
api = connect(username='admin',password='',host='192.168.1.106')
response = api(cmd='/interface/print')
#this the output from the script which I want to convert to dict
({'.id': '*1', 'name': 'ether1', 'default-name': 'ether1', 'type': 'ether', 'mtu': 1500, 'actual-mtu': 1500, 'mac-address': '00:0C:29:3F:B2:27', 'last-link-up-time': 'sep/13/2019 21:50:59', 'link-downs': 0, 'rx-byte': 499795, 'tx-byte': 94132, 'rx-packet': 2180, 'tx-packet': 630, 'rx-drop': 0, 'tx-drop': 0, 'tx-queue-drop': 0, 'rx-error': 0, 'tx-error': 0, 'fp-rx-byte': 0, 'fp-tx-byte': 0, 'fp-rx-packet': 0, 'fp-tx-packet': 0, 'running': True, 'disabled': False},)
```

Comment: It is a dict just in a tuple: `response_dict = response[0]`, you don't even need to call a constructor. Or is there something I am missing from this question?

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Thanks a lot. it worked successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This is the library documentation link: https://librouteros.readthedocs.io/en/3.2.0/path.html#get-all

```
tuple(response)
# This also will work, as well as anything else you can do with iterables
for item in response:
    print(item)
```